# Efficient way to measure region properties using shapely?

Tags: python, performance, geometry, computational-geometry

First of all, I apologize to post this easy question. I have a polygon

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

polygon = Polygon([(560023.4495758876400000 6362057.3904932579000000),(560023.4495758876400000 6362060.3904932579000000),(560024.4495758876400000 6362063.3904932579000000),(560026.9495758876400000 6362068.3904932579000000),(560028.4495758876400000 6362069.8904932579000000),(560034.9495758876400000 6362071.8904932579000000),(560036.4495758876400000 6362071.8904932579000000),(560037.4495758876400000 6362070.3904932579000000),(560037.4495758876400000 6362064.8904932579000000),(560036.4495758876400000 6362063.3904932579000000),(560034.9495758876400000 6362061.3904932579000000),(560026.9495758876400000 6362057.8904932579000000),(560025.4495758876400000 6362057.3904932579000000),(560023.4495758876400000 6362057.3904932579000000)])
```

[image]

My goal is compute the **minor and the major axis** of this polygon, following the Figure example:
[image]

I find this example in [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_regionprops.html) but before to use a second module I wish to ask if there is in shapely module a method to calculate these indices.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

This question is a bit old but I ran into this myself recently, here's what I did:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString

polygon =  Polygon([(560023.4495758876400000, 6362057.3904932579000000),(560023.4495758876400000, 6362060.3904932579000000),(560024.4495758876400000, 6362063.3904932579000000),(560026.9495758876400000, 6362068.3904932579000000),(560028.4495758876400000, 6362069.8904932579000000),(560034.9495758876400000, 6362071.8904932579000000),(560036.4495758876400000, 6362071.8904932579000000),(560037.4495758876400000, 6362070.3904932579000000),(560037.4495758876400000, 6362064.8904932579000000),(560036.4495758876400000, 6362063.3904932579000000),(560034.9495758876400000, 6362061.3904932579000000),(560026.9495758876400000, 6362057.8904932579000000),(560025.4495758876400000, 6362057.3904932579000000),(560023.4495758876400000, 6362057.3904932579000000)])

# get the minimum bounding rectangle and zip coordinates into a list of point-tuples
mbr_points = list(zip(*polygon.minimum_rotated_rectangle.exterior.coords.xy))

# calculate the length of each side of the minimum bounding rectangle
mbr_lengths = [LineString((mbr_points[i], mbr_points[i+1])).length for i in range(len(mbr_points) - 1)]

# get major/minor axis measurements
minor_axis = min(mbr_lengths)
major_axis = max(mbr_lengths)
```

Shapely makes it easy to compute the mbr via `minimum_rotated_rectangle`, but it doesn't appear that the opposite sides are of exact equal length. Because of this, the above calculates the length of each side, then takes the min/max.

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the Minimum Bounding Rectangle of the polygon - see the process described in [How to find the minimum-area-rectangle for given points?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/how-to-find-the-minimum-area-rectangle-for-given-points), except you will start with the convex hull. In Shapely, use the [`.convex_hull()`](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html#object.convex_hull) method to calculate the convex hull of your polygon.

Then once you have the MBR, you can find the major/minor axes.